# How to get collectionView's minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex storyboard

Tags: swift, uistoryboard

I can find many resources on how to set the `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex` value programmatically, but I cannot find how to retrieve the value set in storyboard.

Comment: Why do you specifically need to set this in the storyboard?

Comment: @James I don't but I like to put everything in the storyboard as much as possible to minimize the clutter in the code.